# Powershell exchange server

Tags: c#, powershell, powershell-2.0, exchange-server, exchange-server-2007

I am trying to connect "Exchange Server 2007" from a remote machine using windows powershell. This is how I do.

```
$server = '192.168.1.61';
$pwd = convertto-securestring '123' -asplaintext -force;
$cred = new-object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist 'isshyd\Administrator', $pwd;
invoke-command -computername $server -credential $cred -scriptblock { Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.Exchange.Management.PowerShell.Admin;Get-MailboxDatabase | ft Name }
```

but when I run this query I am getting an error like this

```
Active Directory server "machine name" is not available.
The supplied credential is invalid.
```

The credential I used here is my system credential.

Comment: isshyd is the remote computer name or domain name?

Comment: What if you try the code locally on the remote machine without specifying credentials?

Answer (score 0):

Do you take care of this documentation information.

"To use an **IP address** in the value of the ComputerName parameter, the command must include the Credential parameter. **Also, the computer must be configured for HTTPS transport or the IP address of the remote computer must be included in the WinRM TrustedHosts list on the local computer**. For instructions for adding a computer name to the TrustedHosts list, see "How to Add a Computer to the Trusted Host List" in about_Remote_Troubleshooting."

Comment: In the WinTM TrustedHosts, I have given as *. This should accept any remote machine right. But still its not working.

Comment: What is 'isshyd' the remote computer name or netbios domain name ?